# Plotting Rolling Mean in Subplots from a Data Frame Using a Loop

Tags: python, loops, subplot

I am trying the following code to plot columns from my data frame in a loop along with the rolling mean for each plot. The below loop works for plotting the the column. However, I am having difficulty getting the rolling mean to plot alongside the column data. Any ideas on how I can add the rolling mean to the column data?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(9,1, figsize=(15,30))
ax = ax.flatten()
for n in range(9):
    col_num = str(n+1)
    ax[n].plot(CRday['CR'+col_num])
    CRday.rolling(window=14).mean()['CR'+ col_num].plot()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just took another minute of tinkering!

The following loop works for plotting the rolling mean and raw data where CRday is the data frame and columns are CR1-CR9. Thanks Guys!

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(9,1, figsize=(15,30))
ax = ax.flatten()
for n in range(9):
    col_num = str(n+1)
    ax[n].plot(CRday['CR'+col_num])
    ax[n].plot(CRday['CR'+col_num].rolling(window=14).mean())
```